Laravel and Vue have performance error with LCP
I have a project with Laravel v6 (mix) and vueJs v2
It has LCP error

My website LCP is a hero image that I used it like this
<picture>
                   <source media="(min-width: 1536px)" :srcset="getAssetPath('/v2/assets/images/home-new.webp')" type="image/webp">
                   <source media="(min-width: 1280px)" :srcset="getAssetPath('/v2/assets/images/home-bg-1535.webp')" type="image/webp">
                   <source media="(min-width: 1024px)" :srcset="getAssetPath('/v2/assets/images/home-bg-1279.webp')" type="image/webp">
                   <source media="(min-width: 768px)" :srcset="getAssetPath('/v2/assets/images/home-bg-1023.webp')" type="image/webp">

                   <img fetchpriority="high" class="hero-img" :src="getAssetPath('/v2/assets/images/home-bg-767.webp')" alt="hero image">
               </picture>


ALso, I use extract method in webpack.mix.js
.extract([
        'vue', 'vuex', 'vee-validate', 'lodash',
        'vuetify', 'feather-icons', 'dayjs',
        'tailwindcss', 'masonry-layout',
        'swiper', 'mapbox-gl', 'vue-awesome-swiper', '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw'
    ])

How can i fix that?

Are you generating these webp images on-demand?

@simonhamp, No, These are static

The LCP sub-parts breakdown screenshot shows there is a long delay (9.6 seconds) between the HTML document first being sent to the browser, and the LCP image being requested.
This suggests it's a client side rendered JavaScript app and needs a lot of JavaScript to be run to inject the LCP image into the HTML for the browser to discover it.
Test what renders when JavaScript is disabled. If the LCP resource cannot be seen then that is why the browser is slow here. It's best if you deliver HTML to the browser so it can start fetching resources. If you hide resources in JavaScript then the browser cannot see them until it executes the JavaScript. Can the app be server-side rendered?
After this, there is another large render delay (5.6 seconds) from when the LCP image is fetched, until it is displayed.
How is the image fetched? Is it from a fetch request in the JavaScript? Or is it by the app inserting an <img> tag into the HTML? If it's the former, then you need to look into why there is a large delay after the fetch and before using that resource (maybe it's busy processing something else).
All in all, such large LCP times, and those two sub-parts being large, are classic signs of using too much JavaScript and giving the browser too much work to do the initial render.

Thanks Barry for your answer. I'm using VueJs on the client side, so i fetch images in js component files. What do you think I should do to improve it?

OK so that's why it's slower than the browser being able to get it right away. That's the nature of client-side rendered content I'm afraid. You can potentially preload the content with a <link rel=preload> tag in the HTML so give it a head start so when the JS executes it should have already downloaded and so can be processed right away, but it's difficult to make up the gains of working against the browser like this. This is why many JS frameworks are moving to server-side rendered content (e.g. using Nuxt for Vue apps). Is that an option for you?

Still 17 seconds seems a long time. So need to see if you can optimise the Vue app somehow and require less JS for that initial render. Probably best to open a new question with more details of you app (build options, code included, and bundle size) to ask for advice on that.

To reduce LCP for your hero image in Laravel 6 (Mix) and Vue.js 2:

Optimize Image Size/Format: Use display-sized, compressed WebP images.

Preload Hero Image: Add this to your head:
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="path_to_your_hero_image.webp" imagesizes="(min-width: 1536px)" />

Use a CDN: Serve images via CDN for faster delivery.

Lazy-Load Other Images: Keep fetchpriority="high" for the hero image; lazy-load others.


These steps should help reduce your LCP time.
